# Is it possible to use a sync promise sleep inside of jQuery.each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise, each

So basically. I want to use jQuery's each function within a sync function. 
However, as far as I know. It doesn't work because the each function just checks if the return value is false to break the loop. It doesn't check if its a promise and then sets it to await for it to be resolved. Is there a simple way to make the each function of jQuery synchronous with promises?

I currently have an alternative which is to create a for loop iterating the elements, but its a bit lengthy to write so I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Here is a fiddle of it:
https://jsfiddle.net/3pcvqswn/2/

```
function sleep(ms)
{
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    (async () =>
  {
    console.log("This method works, but its lengthy to write");
    var elements = $("div");

    for(var index = 0; index < elements.length; index++)
    {
        var el = $(elements.eq(index));

        console.log("The content is: " + el.text());

      await sleep(1000);
        }

    console.log("This method doesn't work, but its easier to write");
    $("div").each(async (index, el) =>
    {
        console.log("The content is: " + $(el).text());

      // doesn't wait
      await sleep(1000);
    });
  })();
});
```

I decided to go with `for of`, but a more accurate solution to have both the index and element callback would be

```
  Object.entries($("div")).forEach(async ([index, el]) =>
  {
    console.log("row ", index, el);
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - jQuery's `.each` works similarly to `forEach`. Each callback will be fired off one after the other, and if the callback returns a Promise (such as if it's an async function), it won't be waited for - it works similarly to

```
callback();
callback();
callback();
```

Unless something in the callback *blocks* (which it shouldn't if you're using decent programming practices), nothing asynchronous initialized in the callback can result in further callbacks waiting for that asynchronous action to complete.

But jQuery objects are iterable, so it's trivial to use a concise `for..of` to iterate over the elements:

```js
const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

(async () => {
  for (const elm of $("div")) {
    console.log("The content is: " + $(elm).text());
    await sleep(1000);
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>text 1</div>
<div>text 2</div>
<div>text 3</div>
```

That's not verbose at all IMO.

In order to use `await` in a loop, the loop either has to be a `for` loop (either for..in, for..of, or for(let i = ...), or the loop's iteration mechanism needs to be constructed so that it waits for the last callback to resolve, such as with `reduce`:

```js
const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

[...$("div")].reduce(async (lastProm, elm) => {
  await lastProm;
  console.log("The content is: " + $(elm).text());
  await sleep(1000);
}, Promise.resolve());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>text 1</div>
<div>text 2</div>
<div>text 3</div>
```

---

Side note that's barely worth mentioning - I said earlier that using `await` inside `.each` won't work

> Unless something in the callback *blocks* (which it shouldn't if you're using decent programming practices)

If you write an expensive and silly blocking version of `sleep` which consumes all resources until the next second is reached, it's "possible" to wait inside the loop, but it shouldn't ever be done:

```
const sleep = ms => {
  const now = Date.now();
  while (Date.now() - now < ms) {}
}
```

It's be much better to work with the Promises properly.

Comment: I agree with everything except that while loop you have there. A setTimeout call is non blocking and a while loop is executing an empty loop every tick making your CPU spike to the max.

Comment: That's why I said it's barely worth mentioning. Technically, it fulfills what you're looking for - waiting inside jQuery's `each`, since nothing else can do the job - but it's a horrible idea and, like I said, shouldn't ever be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can't force `$.each` to run serially (one after another). It runs the function for each element "simultaneously". One option is to write your own `each` function that just performs the longer version you wrote in your question:

```js
const serialEach = async (f, elements) => {
   for(let index = 0; index < elements.length; index++) {
       const el = $(elements.eq(index))

       await f(el)
    }
}
```

Then you could run it like this:

```js
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}

$(document).ready(() => {
    const elements = $("div")

    serialEach(async (el) => {
        console.log("The content is: " + el.text())

        await sleep(1000)
    }, elements)
})
```

Note that `serialEach` returns a promise, so it will return immediately and any code you have after the `serialEach` call will execute, even while `serialEach` is iterating over your elements. If you want to wait for that iteration to complete before continuing, you could just `await serialEach` (and make your `$.ready` callback `async`).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt advice to use .each for this. the function gets executed regarless if it's a asynchronous or not. But with programming you can be creative.

```js
//code

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

let promise = Promise.resolve();
$("div").each((index, el) => {
  promise = promise.then(async () => {
    console.log("The content is: " + $(el).text());

    await sleep(1000);
  });
});

await promise;

//code
```